# Mysql2::Error: This connection is in use by: #<Thread:0x00000009a85760 dead>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, activerecord

We are getting the following error randomly on our production environment.

**Error**

```
Mysql2::Error: This connection is in use by: #<Thread:0x00000009a85760 dead>
```

**Setup**

It is a Rails application running on Unicorn. We use threads in our application. We use ActiveRecords with_connection inside each thread to checkout a connection from the connection pool.

```
Thread.new do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
    # Code that writes to DB here
  end
end
```

The error is raised on the first ActiveRecord call inside the new thread. It happens on about 0,5% of our requests.
We have tried to trace a lot of requests, but nothing looks different until it suddenly raise this error.